# Question about orthogonality in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\{u_{1},u_{2},n_{1} \}$ be an independent set in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then these vectors form a basis for  $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Suppose we also know that $n_{1}$ is orthogonal (with respect to some arbitrary inner product) to both $u_{1}$ and $u_{2}$.

Also let $\{u_{1},u_{2},n_{2} \}$ be an independent set in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then these vectors also form a basis for  $\mathbb{R}^3$. Suppose that we also know that $n_{2}$ is orthogonal to both $u_{1}$ and $u_{2}$.

Can I prove that $span\{n_{1}\}=span\{n_{2}\}$ ?

If so, how? Does this apply to $\mathbb{C}^{3}$ as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can make that conclusion. Let $V$ be a 3-dimensional inner product space over $\mathbb F$ (where $\mathbb F = \mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$) and suppose that $\{u_1, u_2, n_1 \}$ and $\{ u_1,u_2, n_2\}$ are two linearly independent sets (hence bases) in $V$ such that both $n_1$ and $n_2$ are orthogonal to both $u_1$ and $u_2$. Since $\{u_1, u_2, n_1 \}$ is a basis for $V$, we can express $n_2$ in this basis; that is, there are some $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \beta$ such that $$n_2 = \alpha_1 u_1 + \alpha_2 u_2 + \beta n_1.$$ But taking the inner product of this equation alternately with $u_1$ and $u_2$ gives \begin{align*} 0 &= \alpha_1(u_1,u_1) + \alpha_2(u_2,u_1) \\ 0 &= \alpha_1(u_1,u_2) + \alpha_2(u_2,u_2)\end{align*} since all the terms $(n_i,u_j) = 0$ for $i = 1,2, j = 1,2$. The only solution to this system is $\alpha_1 = \alpha_2 = 0$ whence $n_2 = \beta n_1$ so $n_2$ is simply a scalar multiple of $n_1.$

Answer (score 0):

Denote $W=span\{u_1, u_2\}$. $W$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ of $dimW=2$. Let's try to figure out what is $W^\perp$. It is known that $dimW + dimW^\perp = dim\mathbb{R}^3 = 3$ and therefore $dimW^\perp = 1$. Now, since $n_1 \perp u_1$ and $n_2 \perp u_2$ we get $\alpha n_1 \perp (\beta u_1 + \gamma u_2)$ for $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in \mathbb{R}$ (Convince yourself) and therefore $W^\perp = span\{n_1\}$.

The EXACT same arguments gives us $W^\perp = span\{n_2\}$, and therefore $span\{n_1\} = span\{n_2\} = W^\perp$.

And of course, the proof holds in $\mathbb{C}$ as well.

Answer (score 0):

Let $N_1 = \operatorname{span}\{ n_1\}$ and $N_2= \operatorname{span}\{ n_2\}$. What you have is that $$N_1^{\perp} = \operatorname{span}\{u_1,u_2\}=N_2^{\perp}.$$

These hold since $M\stackrel{\cdot}{+}M^\perp = V$ for any vector space $V$ with inner product and any subspace $M$ of $V$. What that gives you is that orthogonal complements of both $N_1$ and $N_2$ are two-dimensional and contain $\operatorname{span}\{u_1,u_2\}$, which is two-dimensional as well by linear independence of $\{u_1,u_2\}$.

Now, $$N_1=(N_1^\perp)^\perp = (N_2^\perp)^\perp = N_2.$$